# Django - Why db doesn't raise Exception when User.email is None?

Tags: django, django-models

I wan't `User.email` field to be required. I know that `blank=True` will make it required inside forms but I want to force this on the database level. The weird is that `Django`'s `User` model has `email` with `null=False` by default so I don't understand why I can create a user just doing:

```
User.objects.create(username='foo')
```

And the database doesn't raise any error.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#null), when null is False for a CharField, the default will be an empty string, User.email is an EmailField, which is a subclass of CharField, which means that creating a User without an email address will set email to `''`